# How to estimate MLE with different parameters of functional response?

Tags: r, curve-fitting, mle

I would like to know how to estimate the different parameters p0, p1, p2 and p3 in functional response using maximum likelihood estimation.

How to find a, h in this code, anyone who has done the functional response analysis using mle kindly explain

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you tried a google search on ["R fit holling type 2 mle"](https://www.google.com/search?q=R+fit+holling+type+2+mle)? Can you go look at some of those resources and come back with a more specific question? I assume that the `a` and `h` you're referring to are the attack rate and handling time.  What are `p0`, `p1`, `p2`, `p3`? We need more context and, ideally, a [mcve].

Comment: with(gammarus, plot(density, eaten, xlab = "Prey Density",
ylab = "No. Prey Eaten"))
x <- with(gammarus, seq(from = min(density),
to = max(density), by = 0.1))
lines(x, rogersII(X = x, a = 1.2, h = 0.08, T = 40/24),
col='grey50', lty=2)
lines(x, rogersII(X = x, a = 0.6, h = 0.16, T = 40/24),
col='grey50', lty=2)

Comment: Can you please edit your question into the code? It's still not reproducible: we don't have the `gammarus` data set, and you seem to be using the `frair` package (which contains `rogersII`) even though you haven't said so.  Can you use `rogersII_fit()` ?

Comment: yes sir, i am using the frair package which has an inbuilt dataset of Gammarus. say, If i were to find out the maximum likelihood estimation based on the functional response equation with parameters being intercept or
constant P0, linear P1, quadratic P2, and cubic coefficients P3. How do i get it ? and also in the previous code how do you estimate a, h and T. I do know that its in type 2 equation .

Comment: I don't understand what your P0-P3 coefficients are.  The Rogers curve is not a polynomial (cubic) expression.  Do you want to fit a cubic polynomial instead? Following the examples in the help page, this will fit the Rogers equation: `fit <- frair_fit(eaten~density, data=gammarus,  response='rogersII', start=list(a = 1.2, h = 0.08),  fixed=list(T=40/24))`

Comment: sir please provide your email or email me . i shall be best able to explain you with attached images. stackoverflow is a new platform for me and iam a beginner at r. i shall be very thankful to you if you will drop me a greeting, at this mayurwabhitkar5@gmail.com

Comment: I'm afraid I can't answer questions offline; you're going to have to keep working to improve your question  until it has enough information to be answered.  I'm upvoting your question so that you might have enough reputation to post a link to an image.

Comment: Maybe you could give a link to a paper that does an analysis similar to the one you want to do ?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1csnkNQ-Te3CIISlbhSpHcfcCYpdy_c_I/view?usp=sharing  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Hv_96nUEIhC_TuFFQ0Uyfe4x8GdomllU/view?usp=share_linkhttps://drive.google.com/file/d/1z5yoXq3vc7vFUTW3j27uNG_8WUNTrdul/view?usp=share_link   sir i hope this will do